# Find a second suitable matrix for equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
        -2 & 2 & 3 & -3\\
        1 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

1. Find an invertible matrix P and a Reduced row echelon form matrix D such that: $ PA = D $
2. Find a bases for $ColA$
3. Find a second matrix $Q$ that: $P\neq Q$ and $QA = D$

I've managed to solve questions 1:
$$  D =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 & 3\\
        0 & 0  & 1 & 1\\
        0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
, P =  \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -2 & -3\\
        0 & -1  & -2\\
        1 & 1  & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

and question 2: $$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ -2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

But I don't know how to solve question 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint -

$Q = A^{-1}D$

You already found D and find inverse of A. Then multiply them. You will get Q.